# Foundry fuzzing fails and then passes when parameters are hardcoded

Tags: testing, foundry, overflow

The following test will fail a fuzz test but then works when the same args are hardcoded.

```
function testOverflow(uint256 a, uint256 b) public {
    // UINT256_MAX = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935;
    uint256 maxdiv = UINT256_MAX / b;
    bool overflow = maxdiv * b < a;
    assertTrue(overflow == false);
}
```

Fails under the following conditions:  `[FAIL. Reason: Assertion failed. Counterexample: calldata=0x6abd36c2ffffffffec309a6d62a1ee65e73a3114246c24cdfa83ac91c7235d4b787d4ffe000000001dd41f773eec41adddad8cc49b8cdbfbb8d9238a2e62f7c3e9fd4246, args=[115792089235229943799969063728647219640905739375518871841999069669329936928766, 3141318763523525333446708171302366098197207117370119382021990859334]]`

However, when I hardcode the parameters and switch the assertion from 'false' to 'true', the test fails. e.g:

```
function testFailedOverflowSpecific() public {
    uint256 a = 115792089235229943799969063728647219640905739375518871841999069669329936928766;
    uint256 b = 3141318763523525333446708171302366098197207117370119382021990859334;
    uint256 maxdiv = UINT256_MAX / b;
    bool overflow = maxdiv * b < a;
    assertTrue(overflow == true); 
}
```

Does anyone know what may be the cause of this?